# How to debug SQLite database from SQLite Openhelper?

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

Usually when I want to see the contents of a SQLite database, I use the sqlite3 executable and give it commands like:

```
.open MYDATABASE.db
SELECT * FROM myUserTable;
```

It then outputs my table via command line and it is very easy to see the contents of anything in my database.

Unfortunately, the SQLite database I am working with does not even have an associated .db file.  It extends from a class called SQLiteOpenHelper.  The class resides in a file called DBHandler.java, but obviously attempting to execute command line statements (i.e. as I am used to) fails in this instance.

Does anyone know how to debug a SQLite database that extends from SQLiteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cursor` to see the content of your *sqliteDb* :

```
public Cursor selectRecords() {
   String[] cols = new String[] {USER_ID, USER_NAME};  
   Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, USER_TABLE,cols,null  
            , null, null, null, null, null);  
   if (mCursor != null) {  
     mCursor.moveToFirst();  
   }  
   return mCursor; // iterate to get each value.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to extract your database in an accessible folder on your device :

```
try {
                    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                    if (sd.canWrite()) {
                        String currentDBPath = "/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/yourdatabasename";
                        String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
                        File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
                        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                        if (currentDB.exists()) {
                            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                            src.close();
                            dst.close();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
```

and then open your file.db with your favorite tool.

EDIT : you need to add the permission to write on your device in your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

The database must exist. To find its name see `DBHandler` (if extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`) will have a constructor with something like this:

```
public DBHandler(Context context) {
  super(context, your_database_name, null, your_database_version);
  ...
}
```

The database name can be arbitrary (with or without any extension) and you will find it in `/data/data/<your_package_name>/databases/<your_database_name>`

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/know-where-database-is-stored-in-android-studio/) you will find some advice on accessing this file.

*Warning*: internal file access is granted in emulated devices but real devices must be rooted. You can create an utility method in your app (only in debug mode) to automated the copy process like stated in another answer here.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am aware of this constructor and it is present in the source code.  I found the name in the constructor, but I cannot find the .db file anywhere in the project.  It's name is "movieManager".

Comment: @MrPickles Ok. I guess we are in the middle now. I've updated my answer to give you some more advice on accessing this file. Good work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use intellij idea and database plugin
database plugin can connect to database in your device, for debug very cool ))

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a pluggin to recommend?

Comment: IntellIJ IDEA Ultimate Edition has default database plugin, that can connect to device or emulator, has convenient sql editor and many other feature